# postman render html response and execute JavaScript

Tags: postman

I have an http api that give me `html response`, and I want to "preview" it.

But there is some javascript code in it, and without execute them, it won't give me the right page.

I currently manually copy & paste them in some aaa.html file and use chrome to open it(file://aaa.html), but I want to simplified those steps.

Is there anyway to do that in postman? or is there any postman alternative can do that?

Comment: You can use the Postman Visualizer, put the script into it and it'll work for you.
Read more - https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending-api-requests/visualizer/

The idea would be to send your entire response into the visualizer and then try to render it? I am guessing it might work.

Comment: @SivcanSingh cool feature, but I don't think it's for my requirement. my response is already html with javascript, I just a easy way to render it.

Answer (score 13):

There is an alternative to do this in Postman itself. You will have to use `pm.visualizer`. Just open your API request which is giving you the HTML response. Then go to the *Test* tab, add the lines below, and then click on the *Visualize* tab:

```js
// save your html response in the template and then
const template = pm.response.text(); 

// set that template to pm.visualizer
pm.visualizer.set(template);
```

[image: see in postman]

Comment: Nice, it work. But how about external resource, ex: js, css, jpg? it seems use wrong path(`file:///C:/Users/XXX/AppData/Local/Temp/js/XXX.js`) to load them.

Answer (score 3):

From Postman [official documentation](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/visualizer/)

> Postman provides a programmable way to visually represent your request responses. Visualization code added to the Tests for a request will render in the Visualize tab for the response body, alongside the Pretty, Raw, and Preview options.

You need add to the Tests for a request:

```
    var template = pm.response.text();
    pm.visualizer.set(template);
```

and see result on the Visualize tab (after Pretty, Raw, and Preview options).
[Postman result HTML with JS and CSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JCQEa.jpg)

---

To fix the error:

- `Refused to load the image 'file:///C:/some.png' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "img-src http: https: data:".`
- if the content simply does not find (404 Not Found) it along a similar path 'file:///C:/some.file'

need to add the HTML  tag to the  section of the response body:

```
    var response = pm.response.text();
    var base = '<base href="https://some.domain/">";
    var template = response.replace('<head>', '<head>' + base);
    pm.visualizer.set(template);
```

this answer also solves the question in this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58989684/postman-render-html-response-and-execute-javascript#comment106170384_60018689).

---

For more information:

- Postman [Visualizing responses](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/visualizer/#adding-visualizer-code)
- HTML `<base>` tag [in MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base)